# Meaning of "very purpose"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I am confused about the word "very purpose" what does it mean & where we can use it.

For example:

> It is a canonical question for this very purpose.

As per my English knowledge, I what I can guess is not making sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **very**
>   ADJECTIVE
>   1 Actual; precise (used to emphasize the exact identity of someone or something)
>   ‘those were his very words’
>   ‘he might be phoning her at this very moment’

[source](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/very)

Comment: Even though very meaning is exactly or actual. but the sentences using with very doesn't seem natural . am I right?

Comment: @Arvindraja - No, they seem very natural to a native speaker who's heard the word used in this very manner most of their life.

Answer (score 1):

> It is a canonical question for *this very purpose*.

**This very purpose** is the *purpose defined **just before***, maybe in many words, e. g.:

> I want (= my *purpose* is) *to find out how much you know about hadron colliders*, so
>   I'll ask you a question.

Comment: @Alex_ander- I didn't understand properly yaar.

Comment: The expression can also be replaced with _'exactly for that (the just mentioned) purpose'_.